# Getting conflicting Hardware I/O write speed

Tags: disk, io

I am getting two very different data rate from the dd command as shown below.
**1st**

```
 dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/output conv=fdatasync bs=384k count=1k; rm -f /tmp/output

    1024+0 records in
    1024+0 records out
    402653184 bytes (403 MB, 384 MiB) copied, 0,539091 s, 747 MB/s
```

**2nd**

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test1.img bs=1G count=1 oflag=dsync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1,1 GB, 1,0 GiB) copied, 79,5667 s, 13,5 MB/s
```

One shows 747MB/S and the other 13.5MB/S. Is this due to the caching? **Which one is the correct one?**

Comment: See this excellent answer https://superuser.com/questions/943952/why-am-i-getting-very-slow-dd-dsync-test-results-in-linux

Comment: So does this mean that the correct physical write rate is 747MB/S? I get it different for different options. I sometimes get 100MB/S